# Java Table - AWT

Tags: java, awt, paint

Could anyone perhaps provide me with a link to a tutorial / package that allows the drawing of an HTML like table grid layout? I've googled, but I just keep finding JTable, which won't work for me, and Google keeps wanting to change "java awt table" to "java swt table".

Comment: What do you really want to do? Drawing a table yourself, or arranging components in a table-like layout?

Comment: Why on earth would you be using AWT in this millennium?

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: I want to create a pseudo spreadsheet layout.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: It is the only drawing method supported by the device I'm programming for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't easy.

I think [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) is the closes layout manager, but it is advanced. Remember that you can nest layouts. You can use a layout, then put panels in it and have another layout on the panel.

Comment: Will that work without using Swing?

Comment: @Josh: Most of the layout managers are part of AWT and not Swing, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html